# Xcode: Share assets between multiple targets

Tags: swift, xcode, xcasset

I have an Xcode project with two targets. I want to share assets between the two targets so as to avoid duplicate files.

**What I've tried:**

1. Create SharedAssets.xcassets
2. Add SharedAssets.xcassets to both targets (when you create the .xcassets folder, you can select which targets to add it to)
3. Add a `.wav` file to SharedAssets.xcassets
4. Reference the `.wav` file in code

**Result:**

The `.wav` file can't be found by either target.

**Question:**

Why are both targets unable to find the `.wav` file? How do I share assets between two targets?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I'm using a SpriteKit `SKAction` to load the file from inside an `SKScene`:

```
private var sound: SKAction?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("mySound.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
}
```

I'm then playing the sound like this:

```
if let action = sound {
   self.run(action)
}
```

This strategy works perfectly if I reference a `.wav` file in the main bundle, but fails when referencing the file in SharedAssets.xcassets.

**Edit #2:**

I am able to successfully use *images* stored in SharedAssets.xcassets -- so, it's a problem with *sounds*.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using for step 4. ? Also what are the steps you are taking to add the xcassets file to both targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the `.wav` file in SharedAssets.xcassets, I kept it where it was in the bundle and simply added it to the second target under "Target Membership".

Doing this for each `.wav` file solved the problem.

Comment: Nice one, I was just about to post a reply as looking at [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417664-playsoundfilenamed), it kinda says this in not so many words - "The name of a sound file in the app’s bundle."